# Eclipse 4.2 Linux distros don't ship with internal JRE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java-7, eclipse-juno

I just installed Ubuntu and then downloaded a version of Java 7 and extracted it to where I want `JAVA_HOME`. I then added `JAVA_HOME` as an env var and exported it to `PATH`. I'm now trying to install Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) from [the Older Versions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse) link (specifically [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/r)).

When I download the TAR and extract it to where I want `ECLIPSE_HOME` to be, it extracts a directory named `eclipse`. When I drop into this directory, I see an executable also called `eclipse`.  When I double-click this I get the following error:

[image]

Looking at this directory, I don't see a `jre` subdirectory - it's not even in the TAR that I downloaded from Eclipse's site. My *understanding* of Eclipse is that it always ships with its own JRE. What's going on here?

**Update**

Here's what I put in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/sandbox/java/7u55/jdk1.7.0_55
TOMCAT_HOME=/home/myuser/sandbox/tomcat/7.0.41/apache-tomcat-7.0.41
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$TOMCAT_HOME/bin
```

Comment: You should probably follow [these](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) direction to get Oracle Java 7. Regardless, no - Eclipse does not ship with its' own JRE.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch (+1) - but that doesn't make sense. If the dialog is showing that it's looking for a `jre` subdir inside the current `eclipse` directory, then clearly something is missing from the Eclipse tarball... I know I'm correct here because if I were to download the latest version of Eclipse (4.3) I can fire it up perfectly with no external Java dependencies.

Comment: Eclipse always ships with it's own version of the JRE so you don't run into Java Hell when it is installed on systems with many flavors of Java installed on them. So it's almost as if the Eclipse Foundation stripped out 4.2's JRE when they archived it on their "Older Versions" site.

Comment: No it doesn't mean that necessarily. What is your JAVA_HOME set to? Also, you could install a JRE there.

Comment: Eclipse **never** ships with its' own version of the JRE, because of licensing issues with Oracle. You're thinking of NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks again @ElliottFrisch (+1 on both) - please see my edits that include my `.bashrc` configs. Any ideas?

Comment: change your PATH line, use `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$TOMCAT_HOME/bin`, but you should probably use that webupd8 ppa... it's more in tune with the Ubuntu way. And would let you use `update-java-alternatives`

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I tried your change and it still didn't work (which makes sense, Eclipse is looking for a JRE not the binaries included with the JDK). But then I tried your suggestion to install a JRE directly inside the `eclipse` directory. **So I copied my `JAVA_HOME` (really JDK HOME) `jre` directory to the `eclipse` directory, and now Eclipse is firing right up with no problems.**

Comment: So...my takeaway (for any future-comers) is that it seems as though Eclipse is not looking for `JAVA_HOME` on startup, it is actually looking for a JRE that ships with Eclipse itself. The Eclipse Foundation must remove this JRE (licensing restrictions, perhaps, as @ElliottFrisch suggested) when archiving older versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse supports shipping with an internal JRE, but that is not a requirement and a JRE is never shipped with Eclipse releases. If there is no JRE in the internal directory it tries to find a JRE on the path. Yo can also specify the JRE path in the eclipse.ini file.